# SSMS version number

Tags: ssms

I had SSMS version 13 on my Win 8.1 64bits machine, and just downloaded the latest 16.5.3 SSMS. After installation, the SSMS I opened is still under version  13.0.16106. I tried restarting the computer, but under search, there is only one SSMS available and that is 13.0.16106. I looked into Program and Features, it shows SSMS as 16.5.3 but version under 13.0.16106.

I am confused.. is my SSMS 16.5.3 or 13.0.16106 or is my installation corrupted or incomplete?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I am confused.. is my SSMS 16.5.3 or 13.0.16106 or is my installation
>   corrupted or incomplete?

The [current version](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/sql-server-management-studio-changelog-ssms#ssms-1653-release) of SSMS is `16.5.3` with a build number of `13.0.16106.4`.  This means you have the current version already installed.

> I had SSMS version 13 on my Win 8.1 64bits machine

You no longer have the previous version of SSMS installed on your system.  The previous versions of SSMS *was not 13*, but were preview builds of 16.3, which was released in August 2016.  The major version before 16.3 would be version 12 which was released with MSSQL 2014 which was before the SSMS was seperated from the MSSQL Server release schedule.

*There were of course,  multiple interim releases between 16.3 and 16.5, I just selected the first stable version released since June 2015.*

### Additional Information

- Version 16.3 of SSMS was released around the time MSSQL Server 2016 SP1 was released.
- Version `[Insert Month Here] Preview` was released during/after MSSQL Server 2016 was released
- Version 12 of SSMS was released with MSSQL Server 2014

> In June 2015, Microsoft announced their intention to release future
>   versions of SSMS independently of SQL Server database engine releases.

[SQL Server Management Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Management_Studio#cite_note-3)

[SQL Server Management Studio - Changelog (SSMS)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/sql-server-management-studio-changelog-ssms)

Comment: I must ask.  Is there a reason you reverted your upvote and then issued a downvote?  You know who you are....